# First view in android by using progress bar

Tags: android

I am in the middle of creating an android app and im planning to use progress bar as an introduction for my app. Can u share me some tutorials of using progress bar as the first view.? Then it proceeds to the new view if the progress bar is done

Comment: Are you loading any information while the progress bar is displayed or you just want to show it?

Answer (score 0):

What i would recommend is using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). This will allow you to do background work and update the UI via progress bar.

So here is a quick tutorial on how to use it.

```
private class InsertDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
  private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Main.this);

  // can use UI thread here, and you see we add a progress dialog
  protected void onPreExecute() {
     this.dialog.setMessage("Inserting data...");
     this.dialog.show();
  }

// automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... args) {
    //Do background work here 
     return null;
  }

  // can use UI thread here and we dismiss the progress dialog 
  protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {
     if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
        this.dialog.dismiss();
     }
```